# Save an XML file using JS or convert TXT to XML using JS?

Tags: javascript, xml, file, text, converters

I have been using google for a while and read lots of stuff about parsing from XML with json and other methods. What I could not find is a recent answer to a question? How is it possible to write an XML file using JS or JSON? If that is not possible(as i suppose) then is it possible to convert txt to xml using js or any other way? I want to avoid using PHP in this experiment.

I imagine the conversion as simple as having a string variable which has all the xml file content in it and saving it as a file.

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you want to write this XML file? Where is this javascript running - client or server?

Comment: You can't save a file to disk using javascript. This is for security reasons.

Comment: I want to write the XML file in parent directory relative to index.htm let's say. Main idea about this is to create a mini backend where you can add and remove pictures. It's client side bbut i would not avoid doing some server side as well.

Comment: For **absolutely obvious** reasons you cannot create files on the server from client side javascript. If you want to modify anything on the server consider using a server side script. You could then of course invoke this server side script using client side javascript. For example this could be done with AJAX or some other technique.